# PHP Multi Dimension Array Assignment

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need to fill a multidimensional array and here is my code I have so far for it.

```
while($num > $i)
{
        $default[$i]=0;
        $defaultcounter=0;
        $default2[$i]=0;
        $default3[$i]=0;
        $query="Select * from `issues` WHERE `app`='" . $applist[$i] . "'" . "AND `startmonth`='". $month ."' ORDER BY `id` ASC";
        $result=mysql_query($query);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $downtime[$i]+=$row['duration'];
            $default2[$i]++;    //Number of Incidents Variable
            $defaultcouinter++;
            $times[$i] = array();
            $times[$i][$defaultcounter[$i]]=$row['startday'].$row['starttime'];
        }
        $appavail[$i]=100 -(ceil($downtime[$i] * 100 / $totaltime));
        $default[$i] = (ceil($downtime[$i] / $defaultcounter));
        $i++;
    }
```

Apparently I am not doing the array assignment correct.  I need to to have my number of rows counted with the `$i` variable outside of my while then inside the while the defaultcounter will be keeping up with the column.  I tried just doing a `$time[$i][defaultcounter]` and it didn't like it.  Whats the proper syntax for assigning a multidimensional array?

Thanks

Comment: Querying inside of a loop is bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$times[$i] = array()` should be out (before) the while loop unless you want it redefining `$times` as an empty array in each iteration (reseting values). Apart from that, you're assigning the values correct, although it looks a bit odd (not sure what you want to achieve there). This are the general formulas, should give you an idea:

```
$array[] = $subarray;
$array[$subarray] = $value;
$array[$subarray][] = $value;
$array[$subarray][$i] = $value;
```